# Angular http interceptor with shareReplay and timeout

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a problem in an Angular http interceptor in combination with rxjs `shareReplay` and timeout.

Whenever I do a http get to a backend I also add the rxjs timeout operator to cancel the http request when the backend response time is to large or the user navigates away.

I do this by the following code

```
this.http
  .get<any>(this.url)
  .pipe(timeout(1000))
  .subscribe((result) => {
    // do stuff
  });
```

So in the browser network tab I can see that the request is cancelled as expected:

[image]

When I now use my http interceptor the request is not cancelled anymore

The implementation looks as following (code is simplified to show only relevant parts):

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, shareReplay } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
}
```

[image]

When I now remove the `shareReplay(1)` everything works fine and I do not understand that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, what shareReplay does is that it keeps a subscription to the observable so it can SHARE the REPLAY if you resubscribe to it.

The fact that you are timing out your other subscription only cuts the pipe midway, if I can say so.

Also, I am not sure the shareReplay here is really a good idea. I never really tried it but my guess is that coded like you are doing, this will have no real effect. Because when you will redo an `http.get()` a new observable will be created. What you'd like I think is to save the actual http response in a cache and serve the cache instead.

Also, you could simply put your timeout in your HttpInterceptor BEFORE the shareReplay.